# как запустить PHP скрипт через консоль

Tags: php

у меня есть данный код

```
 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$m2ClTables = $resource->fetchAll("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'm2_cl_%'");

foreach($m2ClTables as $tables){
    $resource->truncateTable($tables['Tables_in_dd (m2_cl_%)']);
    sleep(3);
}
```

я использую для запуска скрипта `/usr/bin/php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dd-magento-1/clear_m2cl_tables.php`

но получаю ошибки

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dd-magento-1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dd-magento-1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(128): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root', Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dd-magento-1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dd-magento-1/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(396): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dd-magento-1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dd-magento-1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dd-magento-1/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dd-magento-1/app/code/core/ in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dd-magento-1/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144
```

На сколько я понимаю, оно не срабатывает из-за того, что я делаю `require_once 'app/Mage.php';`

Как правильно запустить через консоль мой файл, чтобы все срабатывало?(если запустить файл через браузер - все работает)

Comment: Может быть тебе нужен cron? Попробуй в эту сторону копать

Comment: У вас консоль не может подключения к бд

Answer (score -1):

На момент запуска скрипта вам нужно находиться в том каталоге, в котором присутствует подкаталог app с файлом Mage.php.